# WHat is the concept of Unlimited load in performance testing . Is it a fallacy?

Tags: java, performance, loadrunner

Just confused about understanding unlimited load while doing performance testing.Is it measured over time or volume.

Comment: This is the first use of the term "unlimited load" that I have observed in two decades in the profession.   Probably because there is no such item.  All load has an absolute limit, even if it is the finite number of users or devices on the planet

Comment: @JamesPulley you may be right ...but there is so much discussion around it ... I was going throught few blogs which made my head turn . I also think that only the concept of peak load is fine  ....read this blog [link](http://blackanvil.blogspot.ie/2006/06/shootout-load-runner-vs-grinder-vs.html) ....

Comment: It's a knock on license constraint of paying for a particular number of virtual users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "measured over time or volume", but in general unlimited load means that there is no artificial limitation on the load, i.e. the load will be as great as the resources of the system allow.

So, for example, if you are measuring the characteristics of a gigabit network link (yes, I know, this is probably not the use case you're asking about) and limit the load to half a gigabit, you will find that the link latency is very low. The throughput will be then half a gigabit.

On the other hand, if you use unlimited load, information will be transferred as fast as it's possible. Then the latency of the link will rise markedly, and the throughput will be close to the maximum link throughput of a gigabit.

If you want to measure the maximum throughput the system is capable of operating at, then you do want to use unlimited load. But do note that the latency of the system will rise markedly on unlimited load, so if you want to measure latency using a realistic load, then better limit the load.

Comment: Thanks ... I got a bit confused that you cannot feed beyond a certain point to your system ... is that point termed as unlimited load .. the break point of application ....

Comment: No, it is a knock against having to pay for a specific number of virtual users